# what am I doing wrong in regular expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-re

please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I need to get the value

here is the part of the code that is responsible for:

my code:

```
dict_miner['model'] = re.search(r'SN: (\w+)', date.get('Name'))
```

result:

```
'model': <re.Match object; span=(14, 21), match='sn: abc123456'>
```

but I need the value of match to be written to the variable:

my code:

```
dict_miner['model'] = re.search(r'SN: (\w+).group(1)', date.get('Name'))
```

result:

```
'model': None,
```

as a result , why doesn 't it work .group(1)?

```
result = 'model': abc123456
```

or should I throw off the entire code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group(1)` invocation is Python code, not part of the regexp.

```
dict_miner['model'] = re.search(r'SN: (\w+)', date.get('Name')).group(1)
```

Note that this will happily crash if the data does not match; then re.search would return `None`, and you can't call group on `None`. You will need to do this in two steps, like so, to take care of that.

```
name_match = re.search(r'SN: (\w+)', date.get('Name'))
dict_miner['model'] = (name_match.group(1) if name_match else None)
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work(

Comment: "it doesn't work"? What happens? Does your computer e.g. catch fire?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Yes - did you read the second part of my post? (Augmented.)

Comment: See my edit to the post.

Comment: thank you, I'm sorry that I didn't see it somehow I read it by

Comment: if it 's not difficult for you , could you tell me ? And what do I need to write or add so that after a space I throw everything into another variable ?